Relationship between PCA/PLS and Conjugate Gradient Descent
While reading Elements of Statistical Learning here: https://hastie.su.domains/Papers/ESLII.pdf, exercise 3.18 asks to establish a connection between PLS (Partial Least Squares) Regression and Conjugate Gradient (CG) Descent. To that end, I read about CG here: https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~quake-papers/painless-conjugate-gradient.pdf.
Now, upon further thought, I noticed that both PLS regression and PCA regression can be described using CG. This got me confused as to why the author insisted on PLS only. Hence, I want to make sure I don't have an error in my reasoning, which follows.
CG aims to minimize:
$$
f(x) = \frac{1}{2}x^TAx -b^tx + c
$$
where $A$ is positive definite.
In the case of the Least Squares objective, it's easy to see that finding the optimal $\beta$ is equivalent to the minimization problem above where $A=X^TX$ and $b=X^TY$.
Now, both methods (PLS and PCA), regress on orthogonal linear combinations of the columns of X, which is equivalent to finding search directions for $\beta$ that are $X^TX$-orthogonal.
Finally, to compute the magnitude of the move along each of such $A$-orthogonal directions $d_i$, we have the formula for the corresponding coordinate $c_i$
$$c_i = - \frac{\frac{\partial f(x)}{\partial x}^T\cdot d_i}{d_i^TAd_i}$$
where the gradient is taken at iteration $0$ of $x$, namely $x_0$ (take a look at equation (34) in the CG PDF). In the PDF, gradient is minus what is called the residual $-r_0 = Ae_0$ where $e_0$ is the error $e_0 = x_0 - x$.
Using the notation of algorithm 3.3 in ESL, we have $z_i = X d_i$, and when we perform single-variable linear regression, since $z_i$ are orthogonal (which both PCA and PLS achieve), then we get the coefficients,
$$\theta_i = \frac{z_i^TY}{z_i^Tz_i} = \frac{d_i^TX^TY}{d_i^TX^TXd_i}$$
notice that the denominator is equal to that of the equation for $c_i$ above given that $A=X^TX$.
Finally, for both PLS and PCA, we can assume that $\beta$ at the first iteration is $\beta=0$ because we take care of the intercept term first and perform computation on non-intercept features. Thus,
$$\frac{\partial f(\beta)}{\partial \beta}|_{\beta = 0} = X^TX\beta - X^TY|_{\beta=0} = X^TY$$
which proves that the numerators of the two equations are equal. This proves that $c_i = \theta_i$ and we are done.
The main takeaway here is that, in the proof above, we didn't depend on the fact that PLS directions are computed by taking dot-product/correlations between $Y$ and $z_i$ at every step.
Namely, any method that picks an arbitrary choice of orthogonal $z_i$, then performs single variable regression of $Y$ onto each of the $z_i$ is essentially performing CG with a different choice of $A$-orthogonal vectors. Am I right?
